# OpenMP code waits on Join Barrier most of the time

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a piece of code

```
void parallel_func()
{
#pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic) nowait
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
            if (i>j) continue; // hack to allow collapse here
        //...
        }
    }

    #pragma omp critical
    {
    //...
    }
  }
}
```

Using a profiler, I noticed that most of the time my code spends... on waiting on OpenMP *Join Barrier* ... Any idea why? Or how to identify the cause?

~

Answer (score 1):

1. Where is `omp parallel`? I assume that `parallel_func` is inside a `omp parallel` section.
2. It's unclear since you didn't say which join barrier caused huge overhead. In your code, `omp for` does have `nowait`, which means no implicit barrier. You have `omp critical`. This is literally a critical section, so this will not make barrier operations. (If `omp single`, then a join barrier is needed unless `omp single nowait`.
3. So, the only suspected place of join barrier is from the `omp parallel` section, which isn't shown in your code. If the end of `parallel_func` is the end of the `omp parallel` section, and your `omp parallel` doesn't have `nowait`, then the join barrier is from the end of the `parallel_func`.
4. Finally, how to identify the cause? It's mostly because of workload imbalance. The amount of work per each thread might be too highly deviated. This will make some threads are wasting their time on the implicit join barrier. Please identify the workload distribution.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added `parallel`. I used VTune and I noticed that _all_ threads are idle at the end, so it is weird. I also erased almost all of the code, and I got the same effect. Maybe it is some artifact added by VTune...